# Display data inside Template Syntax in popup

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I have a method to show a popup with some data, the function receive some `data` in a array and i need to show it in the popup html.

```
openDetails(data) {
    const self = this;
    // Create popup
    if (!self.popup) {
        self.popup = self.$f7.popup.create({
            content: `
  <div class="popup itemDetails">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="title">{{ data.name }}</div>
          <div class="right"><a href="#" class="link popup-close">volver</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-content">
        <div class="block">
          <p>This popup was created dynamically</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`.trim(),
        });
    }
    // Open it
    self.popup.open();
},
```

This is how the popup looks

[image]

What i´m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<div class="title">${data.name}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="title" v-html="data.name"></div>
```

have you try like this ?

Comment: I try right now and not works, this shows an empty navbar without title text.

Comment: how get values in to data attribute. what did you get when call {{data}}. plz add js file too

Comment: {{data}} is an object, if i use {{ data.name }} in the main html inside the <template> it works perfect. And `data` shows correctly if i do a `console.log(data)` inside the `openDetails()` function, looks like i need to do something to *pass* data inside the popup.